Unfocusable <mat-form-field> - is it possible?
I have a simple form field:
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Some label</mat-label>
  <input matInput type="text"/>
</mat-form-field>

Default behaviour is, that after clicking onto some part of the form-field the form label is assigned different colour - class mat-focused is assigned to the mat-form-field and there is a style with CSS selector .mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-label, which is applied and which assigns different color.
To illustrate:
Stackblitz
I need this style not to be applied and the easiest way I can see is to prevent the class mat-focused from being assigned, in other words to prevent mat-form-field from being focused. Is that possible somehow?
Or any other suggestion?

The simplest way to achieve this is by overriding the css:
Step 1:
Search for the color variable used when mat-focused is not applied (for me it is --mdc-filled-text-field-label-text-color).
Step 2:
add this to your css (update the variable name):


:host ::ng-deep .mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-label {
  color: var(--mdc-filled-text-field-label-text-color) !important;
}



Here is a nice article about ::ng-deep and :host modifiers:
https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-host-context/

If I apply this to the Stackblitz example, which is appended to the question, seems to me like that it resets the color to the user agent's default one instead of the one without mat-focused class. inherit actually says 'please, take parent's style', but since all the color settings are bound with the mat-form-field-label, there is no color style in any of the parents, so the default one is taken.

Thanks for the remark. You need to look for the color variable used when mat-focused is not applied and then use the updated answer.
